# sql function column not available for where clause

Tags: sql

I have a query:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LogId) AS RowNum 
FROM [Log] l
where RowNum = 1
```

and I'm getting the following error:

> *Invalid column name 'RowNum'.*

I did some search here and found that column aliasing is not available in WHERE.

so I tried the the following and it worked:

```
select * 
from 
(
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LogId) AS RowNum 
     FROM [Log] l
) as t
where t.RowNum = 1
```

Is there a better way, from performance point of view, to make this query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sort of performance are you looking at? Ordering, ranking? Here somethig to [check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485680/sql-row-number-over-performance-problem)

Comment: Have you tried replacing `WHERE` by `HAVING` in the first query?

Comment: What RDBMS? **SQL** is just the structured **query language** - no database product.

Comment: @s.bandara: a having without a group by does not make any sense.

Comment: I thought of `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` as something that would have to evaluate, like a `COUNT`, before the condition in the `WHERE` clause. But thanks.

Comment: @s.bandara Everything in the `SELECT` list is evaluated after the `WHERE` clause (to be exact the execution may not follow this order but the results should be as if this order was followed: `FROM -> WHERE -> GROUP BY -> HAVING -> SELECT -> ORDER BY`)

Comment: And window functions, like the `ROW_NUMBER()` are allowed only in the `SELECT` and `ORDER BY` clauses. Because you have to assign row numbers, only after you know how many rows will be returned).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's just the way it is.

Column aliases can not be used on the same logical level where they were defined. You will have to use the derived table (sub-query) as you have found out.

If you are concerned about performance, then don't. The derived table is mere syntactical sugar, it won't make the query slower (compared to the solution you tried first).

Comment: +1, but some databases do allow references to an alias (Teradata for example).

Comment: @GZ Remember to "Accept" an answer that meets your need, and welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: First, thanks for the prompt and detailed answer.

I checked now for the execution plan of both queries (without the where in the query which includes subquery) and the execution plan are exactly the same.

Next time I'll check it first... :)

Thanks!!

Comment: @BobDuell: As you say, some databases may allow references to an alias. I cannot test what Teradata would do in this case but I'd bet it would not allow this. The execution of such a query, if allowed would lead to circular logic because the RowNumbers assigned are affected by the number of the rows that have passed the `WHERE` clause - which would then be affected by the RowNumbers assigned. If the query is something like `SELECT Month(aDate) AS alias FROM t WHERE alias >7`, then OK, some databases may allow it.

Comment: And to clarify, the databases that allow (in the `WHERE` clause) references to an alias do not follow the ANSI/ISO SQL standard.

Comment: @ypercube I was just commenting on the breadth of the statement about aliases. The original question did not name the RDBMS. FWIW, Teradata has an extension (the `QUALIFY` clause) that deals with row selection after window functions.  It also is not ANSI/ISO standard, but I don't personally use any database that is 100% standard.  But I do completely agree with your comments.

Comment: @BobDuell: Thnx, I didn't know about `QUALIFY` and you are right, no DBMS follows 100% the standard - although some try more than others. I should have be more precise, that it would not follow the standard in that specific point.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to this specific query, which won't perform any different but is simpler to write:

```
SELECT TOP 1 <col list> FROM dbo.[Log] ORDER BY LogId;
```

As @a_horse explained, don't be concerned that because your second query looks like more code that it is more expensive. If you want to measure the efficiency of different queries that get the same results, compare their execution plans, not code complexity.

Comment: I need the RowNum in order to get rows e.g. from according to specific criteria.

I cant count on logId.

Thanks

Comment: @GZ then you should include that information in your question, instead of making it look like you're only after the TOP 1.